# Am I correct that the quadrilaterals in this textbook exercise aren't necessarily squares?

Tags: geometry

[image: Problem In Question]

Most people when they look at this problem immediately assume that the quadrilaterals are square but there is no mathematical evidence of this. Am I going insane and seeing things or am correct to say that this problem cannot be solved through mathematics. Please be gentle I am new here.

Comment: Am I correct that the only angles they say are right are at $B$ and at $F$?  It looks like $G$ was drawn in to be right and some of the others.

Comment: The little dashes in the sides mean that they are of the same length, and the little squares in the corners of the quadrilaterals mean that those are square angles. So they are in fact squares

Comment: The picture is not clear. I can't see which angles are drawn to be right angles.

Comment: Only B and  F  are right angles G was From a previous discussion.

Comment: So you posted a poor-quality picture with hand-drawn right angles, and we should have known that we are supposed to ignore them? Please edit your post to make this clear!

Comment: @TonyK Sorry for the inconvenience I updated the the picture as soon as i read comment.

Comment: What's the part **a.** of the question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Part **a** refers to another shape

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You can place the point $A$ arbitrarily and it is always possible to make the triangle $ABC$ isosceles rectangle. The angle $y$ is completely undetermined.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to be 140 degrees, other solutions depends on clarified status of corners at A,D,G,C or at least 2 maybe three of them.

Comment: Angles B,A,D; A,D,C; D,G,F and B,C,D are not given

Comment: @Oakrest Try to make a model from sticks, elastic bands and  fix three corners.